# How to block domain and domain extensions on Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, domain, blocking, spam-prevention

I am getting everyday tremendous amount of junk mails. Some of the senders are as follows.

```
affiliate@smtp17.cpamonday.com
affiliate@smtp22.cpamonday.com
affiliate@smtp36.cpamonday.com
affiliate@smtp39.cpamonday.com 

miracleshake@dfgstuey.xyz
miracleshake@hargrwth.xyz

newsletter@gcbbmz.tk
newsletter@lcoerc.cf
newsletter@pwjawu.tk
```

As you can see the domains names are different every time. I mark one as a junk couple hours later I receive from the same spammer another email.

For the above examples How can I block xyz or top domains? Also I need to block all the emails that coming from cpamonday.com (no matter what is the subdomain names are. I presume the content before the dot is called subdomain).

Is it possible to create a filter method that would block the above and similar spammers?

Comment: Those need to block those in the e-mail server.

Comment: @Overmind I have Apache Spamassassin in cpanel. How can I do it?

Comment: Here's a video tutorial on that: https://youtu.be/FGSU22CJvH8

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is hard as the domain of the sender keeps changing. You have a few options (with option 1 being a direct response to your question).

1. Create a rule which looks to see if the senders email address contains part of a word, such as `cpamonday.` and move them to a junk folder
   a. Right click on a junk email and choose rules, create rules
   b. Click Advanced Options
   c. Choose with specific words in the sender's address
   d. Add the part of the email address (such as the domain) you want to block. You can also add `.xyz`   or `cpamonday.` or `cpamonday.com` 
   e. Click next, Choose what you want to do and complete the wizard
2. Use a junk / spam filter
3. Change your email address (I know it's a naff suggestion but it's still a suggestion)

Comment: I will try this. So, it is not possible to block the whole domain cpamonday.com regardless what's the content before the dot (.)

Comment: The example I've shown. Think of it like contains. So if you put in `cpamonday.com` it will block `a.cpamonday.com` and `abc@cpamonday.com` and `xyas.sadf.as@cpamonday.com.other` etc

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do. I will try it and will let you know the result. Thank you.